# CCheckListBox has bogus vertical scrollbar

Tags: mfc

I can't seem to resolve this issue that has to do with [CCheckListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d58s8sak.aspx).

This is a method that populates the listbox:

```
void CPublishersDatabaseDlg::InitAssignmentsListBox()
{
    UINT uIDs[] = 
    {
        IDS_STR_SOUND,
        IDS_STR_PLATFORM,
        IDS_STR_MICROPHONE,
        IDS_STR_ATTENDANT,
        IDS_STR_MIDWEEK_MEETING,
        IDS_STR_CBS_CONDUCTOR,
        IDS_STR_CBS_READER,
        IDS_STR_ASSIGN_CHAIRMAN,
        IDS_STR_PRAYER,
        IDS_STR_STUDENT,
        IDS_STR_DEMONSTRATIONS
    };

    WPARAM eTypes[] = 
    {
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Sound, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_PlatformAttendant, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Mike, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Attendant, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_OCLM, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_ConductorCBS, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_ReaderCBS, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Chairman, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Prayer, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Student, -1),
        MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Demonstration, -1)

    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        CString strAssignment = _T("");

        if (strAssignment.LoadString(uIDs[i]))
        {
            int i = m_lbAssignments.AddString(strAssignment);
            m_lbAssignments.SetItemData(i, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(eTypes[i]));
        }
    }

    int iNumCustomAssign = theApp.GetNumberSetting(_T(""), ASSIGN_COUNT, 0);
    for (int iAssign = 0; iAssign < iNumCustomAssign; iAssign++)
    {
        CString strAssign, strDescription, strSection;

        strAssign.Format(ASSIGN_TEMPLATE, iAssign);
        strSection.Format(SECTION_TEMPLATE, (LPCTSTR)strAssign);
        strDescription = theApp.GetStringSetting(strSection, ASSIGN_DESCRIPTION_KEY, strAssign);

        if (strDescription != ASSIGN_DELETED) // Skip deleted custom assignments
        {
            int i = m_lbAssignments.AddString(strDescription);
            m_lbAssignments.SetItemData(i, MAKEWPARAM(MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Custom, iAssign));
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed the instructions correctly and set the listbox as **OwnerDraw** and **HasString**.

It seems to work well apart from the vertical scroll:

[image: Vertical scroll issue]

See the highlighted yellow area? That vertical scroll is bogus. If I attempt to click on it the application crashes.

But if I use the mouse wheel to scroll down, then the vertical bar goes away.

How can I get the vertical scroll bar to be correct, like it would be if it was a regular `CListBox`?

I have seen this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473183/mfc-cchecklistboxs-vertical-scrollbar-is-not-updated) but my resource has `WS_VSCROLL`:

```
LISTBOX         IDC_LIST_PUBLISHER_ASSIGNMENTS,177,149,286,110,LBS_SORT | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

I don't know how to resolve this quirk.

Comment: As a start you need to diagnose the issue. Just saying that *"the application crashes"* isn't very helpful. If there is an abnormal termination, you have ways to look at the call stack at the time of the error. Since we don't know what your understanding of *"crash"* is, there is little we can do with the information available. Please provide specific information on the *"crash"*.

Comment: @IInspectable I couldn't reproduce the exception on demand. Odd. I have decided to use another approach. A single column CGridCtrl with a CImageList. I know it doesn't answer the question in hand. But I have a stable way forward now. Thanks.